# MSSQL Background processes that won't go away

Tags: sql-server

Even after rebooting, these processes persist. I need to disconnect all users from the DB to run some end-of-year processes, but these processes from sa won't go away, and I'm at wit's end trying to figure out where they are from. We have several active DBs on this server, but only this DB has all of these processes running.

[image]

Comment: Is the MSSQL Server instance set to start at boot? `LOG WRITER` and `XE DISPATCHER` are both processes that run with the instance whether users are connected to the instance or not. have you verified that there are processes that indicate users are actually connected to it? If there aren't, then there isn't any evident reason that you can't proceed with what you need to do.

Comment: Are these connections actually preventing you from running your end-of-year processes?

Comment: Check the SQL Server Agent jobs or Maintenance Plans.

Answer (score 0):

These processes are inherent to the nature of a service-based DBMS. Even without any connected users, your server will continue to perform certain tasks in the background. These tasks are essential for the maintenance and health of the database system. Therefore, you should not be concerned about these processes. The only way to completely stop them is to shut down the SQL Server service itself.